# onblur firing on window.onload

Tags: javascript, events, onblur

My `onblur` event is firing on `window.onload`.  I suspect I am selecting the node wrong.  When I `console.log(input)` in `function checkList()` it shows `<input name='newTask'>`  Is this the correct way to use `onblur`?

```
app.view = (function(){
    function init(){
        checkList();
    }

    function checkList(){
        var input = document.getElementsByName('newTask')[0];

        input.onblur = checkInput();

        requestAnimFrame(checkList);
    }

    function checkInput(){

        alert('check input');
    }

    return {
        init : init
    }
})();

window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
            function( callback ){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
            };
})();

window.onload = function(){
    app.view.init();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onblur` event isn't firing early, but rather you are calling your `checkInput` function, when you really mean to make an assignment.

Replace `input.onblur = checkInput();` with `input.onblur = checkInput;`